# When typing in text the image is not resizing android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have bellow image vied, everything looks normal i'm have happy with image but there is text view in layout whenever I click to type something the soft keyboard appears and then it take half of the screen but the problem is the image is not shrinking to fit to the layout and the result is cropped image... bellow is the code any idea?

and also I have one image in one drawable not any other images with different size in different drawable like xhdpi etc...

```
<LinearLayout>
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="tes.com">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_grd"
    android:id="@+id/LetterLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Insert Letter"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/entryText"

        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:maxLength="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="check Letter"
        android:onClick="IntroLetter"
        android:id="@+id/checkletter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, the main problem is that the keyboard covers your layout and then the image is cropped? @hi4ppl

Comment: My problem is that when the keyboard appears I want the image to shrink and display everything not to crop it.

Answer (score 0):

you are facing typical clipping which happens all the time, 
go to manifest file and add following attribute to the activity to which this layout belongs to

```
<activity
...
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
/>
```

you may want to change the values depending on how do you want your activity window to behave when softInput Keyboard opens

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">` in your manifest. It will do the trick.